# problemas de cors al llamar a https://webpay3gint.transbank.cl desde angular

Tags: angular, post, transbank

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo un proyecto en angular 9 y estoy llamando por post a la api de integración de Transbank, pero me arroja problemas de cors.

```
obtenertoken(){

const  url = https://webpay3gint.transbank.cl/POST/rswebpaytransaction/api/webpay/v1.0/transactions';
const datosDeCompra = {
  "buy_order": "ordenCompra12345678",
  "session_id": "sesion1234557545",
  "amount": 10000,
  "return_url": "http://www.comercio.cl/webpay/retorno"
}

return this.http.post<any>(this.url, datosDeCompra, { headers: this.vro.headers })
  .pipe(catchError((err) => this.handleHttpError(err)));
```

}

este es el header que ocupo:

```
headers = new HttpHeaders({

    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Tbk-Api-Key-Id': '597055555532',
    'Tbk-Api-Key-Secret': '579B532A7440BB0C9079DED94D31EA1615BACEB56610332264630D42D0A36B1C'
});
```

son los datos que proporcionan desde:
https://www.transbankdevelopers.cl/referencia/webpay?l=http#ambiente-de-integracion

Comment: Puedes indicar el error de CORS que te arroja? Una peticion del lado de servidor no deberia arrojar errores de CORS a menos que se este enviando desde la pagina misma (cliente)

Comment: Hola, si, agrege una imagen del error, si, la api de transbanck la estoy llamando desde el front, el backend que uso es firebase y tambien lo uso como hosting

Comment: cree una nueva pregunta, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/416138/404-not-found-al-llamar-desde-cloud-function-de-firebase-a-https-webpay3gint-t

Answer (score 1):

La API no esta hecha para ser llamada desde un front-end directamente. Expones el API-key y por sobre todo el API-Key-Secret, con lo que cualquier persona podría usar dichos datos para generar transacciones, sobre todo con la API de producción

> Nunca dejes tu código de comercio y secreto compartido directamente en
> tu código, te recomendamos utilizar variables de entorno u otro método
> que te permita mantener tus credenciales seguras.
> https://www.transbankdevelopers.cl/referencia/webpay?l=http#configuracion-para-produccion-utilizando-los-sdk

La solución es usar directamente un backend para tus transacciones, o como minimo, un proxy implementando la API que esconda dichos datos y puedas llamar desde el front-end.

Si no dispones de un servidor backend propio puedes implementarlo en cualquiera de los lenguajes que se indican (PHP Java Ruby .NET Python) y utilizar algún servicio como Heroku para poner en marcha el servicio de manera dinámica/a petición.

Comment: Hola, cree un servicio en cloud function de firebase que llama a la api de integracion de transbank pero me arroja un 404 Not Found, "The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.", voy a agregar la info a la pregunta

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, cree una nueva pregunta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/416138/404-not-found-al-llamar-desde-cloud-function-de-firebase-a-https-webpay3gint-t

Answer (score 0):

No debes llamar a transbank desde el front(tu app en angular), debes crear un backend y llamar desde ahi.
Entonces debes un api en el backend(node, python, java, etc) y generar un endpoint al cual consultes a transbank y esa respuesta a expones para angular y desde tu cliente en angular consumes tu backend, y es muy probable que el problema también tenga que ver con que lo estas llamando en localhost y no te lo está aceptando... ideal que pusieras una captura con la respuesta que te envía transbank, pero la mayoria de las veces el problema de cors será por que lo llamas desde el localhost.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, agregue una imagen del error, el backend que tengo es firebase y lo uso como hosting tambien

Comment: No debes llamar a transbank desde el front, es por seguridad o por que técnicamente no es posible?

Comment: Esto es por seguridad...
y firebase no es un backend, te ayuda en el manejo de tu info, pero no es un backend

Comment: con cloud function de firebase se puede crear microservicios y disponibilizarlos con token, eso debería bastar, cree uno para que me llame al servicio de integracion de transbank pero me arroja 404 Not Found, "The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.", voy a agregar la info a la pregunta

Comment: cree una nueva pregunta al final, gracias por la ayuda. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/416138/404-not-found-al-llamar-desde-cloud-function-de-firebase-a-https-webpay3gint-t