# {"error_message":"Not Authorized"} al llamar desde cloud function de firebase a https://webpay3gint.transbank.cl de transbanck

Tags: firebase, cloud, transbank

Hola cree un servicio en cloud functions de firebase para llamar a la api de integración de Transbank, el problema es que no responde con el token de prueba si no que con un {"error_message":"Not Authorized"}, pero al llamar a la url de Transback directamente por postman si me retorna un token y una url.

mi codigo en cloud functions es el siguiente:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express')
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express()
const axios = require('axios');
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

 app.post("/api/token", (request, response) => {
    const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Tbk-Api-Key-Id": "597055555532",
        "Tbk-Api-Key-Secret": "579B532A7440BB0C9079DED94D31EA1615BACEB56610332264630D42D0A36B1C"
    };
    const url = "https://webpay3gint.transbank.cl/rswebpaytransaction/api/webpay/v1.0/transactions";
    const datosDeCompra = {
        "buy_order": "ordenCompra12345678",
        "session_id": "sesion1234557545",
        "amount": 10000,
        "return_url": "https://www.mydominio.cl/"
    }
    try {
        axios.post(url, datosDeCompra, headers)
            .then(r => {
                console.log("data => ", r.data);
                return response.send(r.data);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log("error =>", e.response.data);
                return response.send(e.response.data);
            })
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).send(error);
    }
})
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

los headers, url y datosDeCompra son los datos que proporcionan desde: https://www.transbankdevelopers.cl/referencia/webpay?l=http#ambiente-de-integracion

al llamar al servicio de integración de Transbank, este me responde Not Authorized

```
errorStatus => 401, Unauthorized
{"error_message":"Not Authorized"}
```

SOLUCION ENCONTRADA===========>

estaba pasando las cabeceras de forma incorrecta, en otro post encontre la respuesta : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617825/passing-headers-with-axios-post-request

Comment: Disculpa si me exprese de forma incompleta, el segundo pedazo de código que sale mas arriba corresponde a la respuesta que entrega el servicio de integración de Transbank que es este: https://webpay3gint.transbank.cl/POST/rswebpaytransaction/api/webpay/v1.0/transactions y que escapa a mi control.

Comment: El error 401 indica que los datos de autorizacion no son correctos o fueron enviados de manera incorrecta. Puedes revisar si el api-key-id y api-key-secret son los correspondiente al ambiente de integracion (`webpay3gint `) y no los de produccion? Tambien revisa si existe alguna restriccion de host que puedan conectarse al endpoint y agregar el servidor de donde se conecta

Comment: hola, gracais por responde, al final de la pregunta coloque la respuesta que encontre, no se bien como dar por solucionada la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

El error 404 indica de modo general que el recurso no existe, en realidad esta url no existe:

```
const url = "https://webpay3gint.transbank.cl/POST/rswebpaytransaction/api/webpay/v1.0/transactions";
```

Me parece que tienes un malentendido, para realizar una transacción, lo que debes realizar es una petición POST pero hacia la url :

```
const url = "https://webpay3gint.transbank.cl/rswebpaytransaction/api/webpay/v1.0/transactions"
```

esta petición debe realizarse usando los headers que tienes definidos:

```
const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Tbk-Api-Key-Id": "597055555532",
        "Tbk-Api-Key-Secret": "579B532A7440BB0C9079DED94D31EA1615BACEB56610332264630D42D0A36B1C"
    };
```

y obtendrás una respuesta parecida a :

```
{
 "buy_order": "ordenCompra12345678",
 "session_id": "sesion1234557545",
 "amount": 10000,
 "return_url": "http://www.comercio.cl/webpay/retorno"
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, por lo que lei en la documentación, hay que pasarle esos datos de compra para que cree la transacción y retorne un token y una url, pero tienes razón en lo de url, le saque el "POST" y funciono, pero solo cuando invoco directo a esa url por postman, cuando lo invoco por medio del servicio me responde Not Autorized

Comment: Si te funciona usando Postman, entonces el problema ahora es que tu función tal vez no tenga permisos, o tenga un problema de Cors.

Comment: estaba ingresando de forma incorrecta los headers, al final de la pregunta coloque la respuesta, no se bien como dar por solucionada la pregunta, gracias por la ayuda :)